# Social integration with Auth0 in Android

Tags: android, authentication, auth0

I am integrating Google and facebook in Android with Auth0 method. All config are correct but I am little confuse in callback URL which is need to enter in Auth0 console setting.

When I try to run the app I am getting "Callback Url mismatch"

Check below image:-

[image: I am getting this error]

Now which URL I need to enter in console setting, and what content must be there in URL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter whatever url you are going to redirect to after the authentication into the allowed callback urls in the auth0 dashboard.

Comment: But it is not allowing normal url

Comment: can you post the uri with any sensitive info scrubbed

Comment: Can you post an example of the uri you are trying to use

Comment: In the instructions it states "Make sure to specify the protocol, http:// or https://, otherwise the callback may fail in some cases."

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I was running into the same issue and finally figured out why.  When using IOS and Android the callback scheme used is myapp and not localhost or whatever domain you are using.  To resolve the issue I had to enter in both urls into the callback url (Application URIs) in addition to updating the manifest and info.plist.  I'm using a windows host file redirect to associate my non existent domain to my localhost while developing so my URIs look like this which corrected the error for me.

`https:\\mytestdomain.com\api\auth, myapp:\\api\auth`